# Converting SVG to PDf in node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, svg, npm, io.js

I am working on converting an SVG to a PDf document.Is there any module in node.js that helps with this.

I have found https://www.npmjs.com/package/librsvg

But I am having issues setting it up.Is there any module which is simpler to setup?
Is there any other way to convert to pdf via node.js. I already have SVG converted to png.All I need is to convert it to PDF

Comment: What have been your issues with installing librsvg? I only ask as other options ([node-inkscape](https://github.com/papandreou/node-inkscape) for example) require the same kind of setup as rsvg.

Comment: please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1

Comment: It might be worth appending 'on Windows' to your question title, as a Windows installation of a lot of external libraries (such as rsvg, inkscape, imagemagick, pdftools etc.) involves a similar level of complication, and any answers you get to the question in its current form will probably lead you to the same problems.

Comment: Converting an svg file into PDF by going through a raster image like png is almost a crime... svg is a vector-based format, as PDF, using png as intermediate format will provoke unnecesary loss of quality in the output

Comment: @yms and wayfarer_boy  Thanks for the help .I was able to get inkscape to work for me.Thanks a ton